# use of .apply() for comparing elements

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe **df** of thousands of items where the value of the column "**group**" repeats from two to ten times. The dataframe has seven columns, one of them is named "**url**"; another one "**flag**". All of them are strings.

I would like to use Pandas in order to traverse through these groups. For each group I would like to find the longest item in the "**url**" column and store a "0" or "1" in the "**flag**" column that corresponds to that item. I have tried the following but I can not make it work. I would like to 1) get rid of the loop below, and 2) be able to compare all items in the group through df.apply(...)

```
 all_groups = df["group"].drop_duplicates.tolist()

 for item in all_groups:

     df[df["group"]==item].apply(lambda x: Here I would like to compare the items within one group)
```

Can apply() and lambda be used in this context? Any faster way to implement this?

Thank you!

Comment: Posting an example DataFrame with intended output would be helpful.

Comment: `.apply` isn't fast. It should be used as a *last resort* since it is simply a wrapper around a python for-loop, with a little house-keeping, making it *slower* than a straightforward for-loop many times. Why don't you provide an example of the input data, and and example of the output you are expecting...

Comment: You may find `.groupby().transform()` more useful than `.apply()`.

Comment: @AChampion likely some `df.groupby('group').transform(...)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes indeed, you beat me to the update to my comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `groupby()` and `.transform()` you could do something like:

```
df['flag'] = df.groupby('group')['url'].transform(lambda x: x.str.len() == x.map(len).max())
```

Which provides a boolean value for `df['flag']`. If you need it as `0`, `1` then just add `.astype(int)` to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you write code and find it's running slowly don't sweat optimizing it. In the words of [Donald Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

If you want to use `apply` and `lambda` (as mentioned in the question):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'url': ['abc', 'de', 'fghi', 'jkl', 'm'], 'group': list('aaabb'), 'flag': 0})
```

Looks like:

```
   flag group   url
0     0     a   abc
1     0     a    de
2     0     a  fghi
3     0     b   jkl
4     0     b     m
```

Then figure out which elements should have their flag variable set.

```
indices = df.groupby('group')['url'].apply(lambda s: s.str.len().idxmax())

df.loc[indices, 'flag'] = 1
```

Note this only gets the first url with maximal length. You can compare the url lengths to the maximum if you want different behavior.

So `df` now looks like:

```
   flag group   url
0     0     a   abc
1     0     a    de
2     1     a  fghi
3     1     b   jkl
4     0     b     m
```

Comment: Advice taken. My earlier code executed quite slow; with your suggestion (and clear example) and particularly @AChampion use of .transform, I was able to do away with the loops and execution took 30 seconds rather than 20 min. This has been immensely helpful.